# Remote Desktop with few options: troubleshooting

Tags: networking, router, remote-desktop, vnc

I need to remote desktop my laptop to my pc. They sit right next to each other.

The laptop and the PC are on different DNS, Subnet, and Gateway addresses. (They are using different routers). So I believe that I cannot remote desktop/VNC. I also do not have administrative access to these routers.

The PC only has one ethernet port (which is in use for the internet connection) so I cannot use a cross over.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Give teamviewer a try - it communicates over 80 and 443 so it should be allowed.   Teamviewer is similar to RDP or VNC (you see the desktop of the target computer)..

http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx

Here is a quick tutorial explaining how teamviewer works and how to configure it

http://www.wikihow.com/Use-TeamViewer

Comment: John, did this answer your question?   If so, please mark this as the answer.   If not, please provide more detail so someone here can further assist you.